# VBA how to open a excel file and tell its creation date

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to open a file from somewhere and also get the date when the opened file was created. However the line below gives me an error "Run Time Error, Automation error and Unspecified error". How can I fix this? Thanks.

> MsgBox wb2.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date")

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim Ret1, Ret2
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

    'Clear Summary tab
    wb1.Worksheets("Summary").Cells.Clear


    'Delete existing worksheet with name "Task List Data Export"
    For Each WS In Worksheets
    If WS.Name = "Task List Data Export" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets("Task List Data Export").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End
        End If
    Next

    'Get the File
    Ret1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
    , "Please select file")
    If Ret1 = False Then Exit Sub



    'Copy file
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Ret1)

    MsgBox wb2.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date")

    wb2.Sheets(1).Select
    wb2.Sheets(1).Copy After:=wb1.Sheets(2)


    'Close opened file
    wb2.Close savechanges:=False
    Set wb2 = Nothing

    Worksheets("Cover").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: `. If Microsoft Excel doesn’t define a value for one of the built-in document properties, reading the Value property for that document property causes an error.` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197172.aspx

Comment: Would you be interested in an alternative way to get the creation date?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Rout Yes please. Any way will do. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If Microsoft Excel doesn’t define a value for one of the built-in document properties, reading the Value property for that document property causes an error.

From [Workbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197172.aspx)

There is always a file created date and hence it is quite surprising that you are getting that error. I have never got this error. Even a newly created file which has not been saved gives you a "File Created Date and Time".

Here is an alternative.

```
Dim CtdDate As String
Dim fs As Object, f As Object

Ret1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
                                   , "Please select file")

If Ret1 = False Then Exit Sub

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fs.GetFile(Ret1)

CtdDate = f.DateCreated

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Ret1)

MsgBox CtdDate
```